# Нужна ли запятая в предложении перед и

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед и?

В случае возникновения осложнений при применении препарата его использование прекращают и потребитель обращается в учреждение...

Answer (score 2):

Правильно **без запятой:**

***В случае возникновения осложнений при применении препарата** его использование прекращают ***и*** потребитель обращается в учреждение...*

**Пояснение**

1. Запятая не ставится в ССП при наличии **общего обстоятельства**.

**[Розенталь, пункт 2](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)**

Перед союзами и, да (в значении и), или, либо запятая не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения объединены каким-либо **общим элементом**. 1) Общим может быть **второстепенный** член предложения: ***Вскоре после восхода** набежала туча и брызнул короткий дождь (П.).*

2. Обычно вызывает затруднение вопрос об отнесенности обстоятельства **к одному или обоим** предложениям в состав ССП.  В текстах **информационного** характера  важна **формальная** грамматика, а **реальные** причинно-следственные отношения  между простыми предложениями можно не учитывать.  Предложения считаются **однородными и независимыми**, поэтому обстоятельство будет общим.